# htaccess rewrite rules trouble [L]

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Can anyone help me please with `.htaccess`?

I have a folder system on my site:

- user

  - index.php
  - profile.php
  - login.php
  - other pages.php
- page

  - contact.php
  - products.php
- index.php

When someone comes to my website example.com it shows the index.php page. I use `.htaccess` to have clean URL's.

`example.com/contact` must include `/page/contact.php` into index.php.

`example.com/user/username/profile` must include `/user/profile.php` into user/index.php.

example.com/products/spinningbike include product.php into index.php and shows the details of product spinningbike.

This is my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^login /user/login.php [L]
RewriteRule ^user/(\w+)/?$ /user/index.php?id=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1
```

I always get these php errors in my log files:

> PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening 'page/user.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in
>   /home/example.com/public_html/index.php on line 115, referer:
>   http://www.example.com/user/wim/profile PHP Warning: 
>   include(page/user.php): failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in /home/example.com/public_html/index.php on line 115,
>   referer: http://www.example.com/user/wim/profile

I think the `[L]` is not working properly.

Comment: this is not related to apache and htaccess, this is a PHP error. on line 115 of `index.php`, your script tries to include the file `page/user.php` which does not exist.

Comment: Normally the `.htaccess` should stop at the second rewriterule, so my last rewrite rule should not be excecuted. That's why I get that php error.

Comment: No because the 2nd rule matches urls like `http://example.com/user/username/` as you have "profile" at the end of the url, the last rule is used

Answer (score 0):

with the htaccess defined like this, the url `example.com/user/username/profile` will be matched with the last rule. because the 2nd rule will only match the urls of this format : `example.com/user/[any word character]`

`word characters` are `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `_`.

You have to change the 2nd rule to match this url

```
RewriteRule ^user/(\w+)/(\w+)/?$ /user/index.php?id=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

This way, the url `example.com/user/username/profile` will be rewritten `example.com/user/index.php?id=username&page=profile`

Answer (score -1):

First, `page/user.php` does not exist in your current "folder system".

Then, even if it exists, it can maybe not work if you are using something like XAMPP, WAMP or MAMP because these softwares use a default root directory that is maybe not yours.

For exemple, in XAMPP this directory is `C:\xampp\htdocs` so, if your project is in a file (for exemple `myProject`) in this default directory, your URL to see the project render will be `127.0.0.1/myProject`.
Considering this, if you redirect to `/page/user.php` the redirect URL will be `127.0.0.1/page/user.php` BUT you want to hit `127.0.0.1/myProject/page/user.php` (C:\xampp\htdocs\page\user.php does not exist, so an exception is generated)

In XAMPP, to change the default root directory for the Apache webserver, you must edit the following lines:

`DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">`

to

`DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/myProject"
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/myProject">`

in `C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf`

Comment: i don't think this answers the question.